# Wait for end of Loading Data from Web API iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have Method using Web API for load data from my Server.
It works but when process of loading Data is in processing(not finish).
Other method is processing.
I want process of loading data finish before do other process.
How to fix it.

This is my example code.

```
-(void) test
{
    [self updateDataFromServer];
    [self showData];
}

-(void) updateDataFromServer
{
     [DataClient loadDataAfterAuthentication:self.userName whenCompleted:^(BOOL success, NSMutableArray *dataes, NSError *error)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             // do some thing...
         }
         else
         {
             // do some thing...
         }
     }];
}

-(void) showData
{
     // do something
}
```

when method `updateDataFromServer` in processing(not finish) method `showData` is in process too.
i want "Loading" statement for this problem.

example "waiting authentication" alertView

if `updateDataFromServer` completed,  waiting authentication AlertView disable and do Method `showData`.

Sorry about my question and my english.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you put your `[self showData]` call inside the `whenCompleted` block of your `loadDataAfterAuthentication` call?

Comment: sorry for my question. I mean if i have other method EX: [self checkData] behind [self updateDataFromServer]. in method checkData All Data is Null. I want to wait for [self updateDataFromServer] End.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the `showData` in the success statement. For the "Loading" statement, you use a `UIActivityIndicatorView`. Start spinning when `updateDataFromServer`, and stop it when it's done.

```
-(void) updateDataFromServer
{
     //Start spinner
     [DataClient loadDataAfterAuthentication:self.userName whenCompleted:^(BOOL success, NSMutableArray *dataes, NSError *error)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             [self showData];
             // Disable spinner
         }
         else
         {
             // do some thing…
             // Disable spinner
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: sorry for my question. I mean if i have other method EX: [self checkData] behind [self updateDataFromServer]. in method checkData All Data is Null. I want to wait for [self updateDataFromServer] End.

Comment: You can put what ever method you want in the `whenCompleted` block when `updateDataFromServer` ends.